# Update local reference for remotes without pushing

Tags: git, git-reset, git-fetch

I'm developing a team script for fetching & pulling and need to test fetching. How do I modify my local version of the remote reference (without pushing) so that a fetch command will update my remote reference?

My repo is:

```
$ git show-branch
* [master] Merged PR 2
 ! [test] Merged PR 1
--
*  [master] Merged PR 2
*+ [test] Merged PR 1

$ git show-ref
09fc4e93cc5635589de5cf370b72a8133b20c64f refs/heads/master
bdf9bd23654ae2f0957742fa521958125abbdb11 refs/heads/test
09fc4e93cc5635589de5cf370b72a8133b20c64f refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
09fc4e93cc5635589de5cf370b72a8133b20c64f refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I'd like `refs/remotes/origin/master` at `bdf9bd23654ae2f0957742fa521958125abbdb11` but `refs/heads/master` to remain at `09fc4e93cc5635589de5cf370b72a8133b20c64f`

Just to be clear - I'm *not* asking about updating the origin, just my (local) references. I *do not* want to do `git reset --hard test; git push --force` - I don't think a push should be involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it; I was looking for `update-ref`:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master bdf9bd23654ae2f0957742fa521958125abbdb11
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `git fetch origin master` work? Or will that update your version of master as well?

Comment: That doesn't move my master branch backwards; it just updates master & the FETCH_HEAD and doesn't fetch any other branches beside master.